# Using a string to access a get method in themes

Tags: flutter, dart

So basically, I want to be able to use a line of code like:

```
body: Container(
  height: getDimension(context, true, 'homeContainer');
)
```

but I don't know how I would go about using the String type to access the data in my theme extension.

```
extension CustomDimensions on MaterialTapTargetSize {
  //double get 'name' => 'dimension';
  double get 'homeContainer' => 1.0;
}

double getDimension(BuildContext context, bool isHeight, String type) {
  double value;
  isHeight ? value = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * Theme.of(context).textTheme.$type : null;
  return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension CustomDimensions on TextTheme {
  double type({String data}) {
    if(data == 'homeContainer')
      return 1.0;
    else
      return 0; // else code
  }
}


double getDimension(BuildContext context, bool isHeight, String type) {
  double value;
  isHeight ? value = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * Theme.of(context).textTheme.type(data: type) : null;
  return value;
}
```